# Be careful with latest MikTeX update: MSVCP140_CODECVT_IDS.dll missing

Tags: miktex, updating, miktex2.9, bugs, missing

I noticed that almost all of the MikTeX binaries were updated (looks like they were released today). After backing up my install (if you don't do this before applying updates, you should...), I applied the updates -- right at the end of the process, an error is thrown:

[image: MikTeX update bug]

> The program can't start because `MSVCP140_CODECVT_IDS.dll` is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix the problem.

If I exit the update console, and try compiling an MWE, even from the command line, same error. I can replicate this on multiple machines -- so it isn't something 'missing' from any one of them. For completeness, I'm using 64-bit MikTeX, 2.9.

Whats weird is that if you search for this particular 'missing.dll', it doesn't show up at all on Google -- no mention of it whatsoever. Same with Bing...nada.

I haven't tried a 'file by file' update, to see if its one particular binary (since that doesn't always work when all the binaries have been updated), but I might.

In the meantime -- I urge caution. Your results might vary, but unless you have a backup to roll back to, latest mega-update to the MikTeX binaries might bork your install. Completely.

I sent an email to the MikTeX maintainer, letting him know there *may* be a problem.

Comment: What is your question? Bug reports should be made to the maintainer (as you already did: thanks for that :-). Bug reports aren't exactly in the Question and Answer format of this site, so I'm afraid your post will be closed.

Comment: So, is there a better way then to alert the larger community? If I find a bug *(like the pgf bug I stumbled into last couple of days), I both file a bug report (or alert maintainer), and post something here -- in the 'community spirt' of trying to help people avoid doing something that might compromise their install. Sure, it isn't a question, but there ought to be some accomodation for this sort of thing. If a bug isn't made widely known, then a bunch of people might try something, have it not work, and then hop onto StackExchange asking questions which are simply artifacts of the bug.

Comment: It's really nice of you to do that, but unfortunately the site has some strict rules in the Q&A format, so unfortunately this will be closed (although it will not be deleted, so people can still find it). You can post this at a TeX (or perhaps a MiKTeX-specific) mailing list, though.

Comment: Well, the obvious question would be: Can this problem be fixed without waiting for a MiKTeX update? What I would try to do is to look for `msvcp140.dll`, make a copy of that file, rename that to the file name from the error message and store it somewhere MiKTeX can find it.

Comment: This bug should be reported here: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues

Comment: I just do it https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/346

Comment: related : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501795/msvcp140-codecvt-ids-dll-was-not-found-miktex-2-9

Comment: The MikTeX package database has been taken off-line temporarily to avoid spreading the broken update, see https://miktex.org/alert/update-problem-7147.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a “bug alert” that cannot receive an answer.

Comment: The problem has been resolved. People who didn't get the corrupted update can just update normally as of today. People who got the corrupted update need to get hold of the updated infrastructure packages (not sure how that works when even the Console fails to open, worst case a re-install should work, but maybe there is a cleverer way ...).