# MSVCP140_CODECVT_IDS.dll was not found [MikTex 2.9]

Tags: miktex, miktex2.9

Opened MikTeX Console to perform an update to the installed modules, and an error occurred during the installation of one or more modules. This prompted the following message to keep appearing:

> The code execution cannot proceed because MSVCP140_CODECVT_IDS.dll was
>   not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.

MikTeX Console cannot be opened without the error reappearing. Running the default uninstaller for MikTeX triggers the same error message (pointing to a corrupted MikTeX installation).

Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: related : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501786/be-careful-with-latest-miktex-update

Comment: This bug is reported here: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/346

Comment: The MikTeX package database has been taken off-line temporarily to avoid spreading the broken update, see https://miktex.org/alert/update-problem-7147. Updates are therefore not possible at the moment. Updates will be re-enabled when the fixed version is available (hopefully soon, but there might be a delay until all mirrors catch up with the update).

Comment: The MikTeX developer explains where to get the necessary `.dll` in https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/346.

Comment: I was able to get MikTeX working today (29/07/2019) by reinstalling MikTeX (after first deleting the program files) and running the normal package update procedure within the console. This suggests that the problematic update package has been fixed/removed. I did not require the DLL patch as listed below.

Answer (score 2):

The developer outlined how to install the missing `dll` in the corresponding [Github issue](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/346):

- Download the latest Visual C++ redistributable package from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads). (Depending on your processor, that is the file `vc_redist.x64.exe` (64 bit processor), `vc_redist.arm64.exe` (64 bit ARM processor) or `vc_redist.x86.exe` (32 bit processor).
- Run `initexmf --mklinks --verbose --force` in the command line (`cmd` or PowerShell). You can open PowerShell by right-clicking on the Windows button and selecting "Windows PowerShell (Admin)".

Comment: Have you tested this yourself?

Comment: @AndréC I have not (I do not have the corrupted update, so I can't). It has been tested, though (according to Ulrike Fischer in the issue comments, which is good enough for me).

Comment: Ulrike is a great professional, I'm not sure that an amateur can do it as well as she can...

Comment: Tried to recreate the error today (29/07) while I was reinstalling MikTeX and it appears the problematic package has been fixed/removed in the updates. This patch may no longer be necessary.

Comment: @jofa Since [the issue](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/346) is still open, I guess the bug has not been fixed but rather the update been retracted. Nobody who has not had the corrupted update before should be getting it, though.

Comment: The issue has been fixed. MikTeX has updated the https://miktex.org/packages/miktex-vc140-bin-x64 package that ships the necessary `.dll`s (you can verify that at https://miktex.org/Package/Browse/miktex-vc140-bin-x64). I didn't update my system yesterday due to the bug, but I did so just now: Everything is working as expected and without errors even though I did not download or install `vc_redist.x64.exe` from the MS site.