# Miktex won't connect to repository server

Tags: errors, miktex, update

i've tried to install some new packages, but it failed. Then I tried to update my miktex manually from the console and got this error:

[image: miktex error 503]

Wehen i had a look at the [www.miktex.org](https://miktex.org) website, there was no notification, that there is a maintanance going on.
So i tried o set a repo proxy manually from this list: [enter link description here](https://miktex.org/pkg/repositories)

For me it was: **ftp.rrze.uni-erlangen.de** with the protocol **http**, so as port i entered **80**. But as i tried to install new packages or update, i got this message:

[image: miktex error 56]

Even adding "http://" infront of the url didnt change anything.
Then I just downloaded the repos manually from https://mirror.informatik.hs-fulda.de/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/ to a local directory and entered the link in the miktex console. With this, i got this error:

[image: miktex error 4]

So am i doing wrong? Its very tedious to download all repos manually.

Comment: Due to the issues discussed in https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/346, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/501786/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/501795/35864 MikTeX has temporarily taken the repositories offline, see https://miktex.org/alert/update-problem-7147

Comment: The issue should be resolved in a few days. If you absolutely *need* to download or update a package right now, you'll probably have to go through a local package repository as suggested by u-fischer in the MikTeX bugtracker see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462203/35864

Comment: Thanks @moewe now it works like before. But how do you add the proxy with port? As i did it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was due to a temporary shutdown of the MiKTeX repository that is over now.