# MiKTeX Console Updates Error: 503

Tags: miktex, miktex-update, console

I'm use MIKTeX in windows and i can not update the packages, when i press the **Check for updates** button, it return an error, here is :

My computer configuration:

```
MiKTeX: 2.9
OS: Windows 7 Ultimate, 64-bit, Service Pack 1, build 7601
SharedSetup: yes
PathOkay: yes
SystemAdmin: yes
RootPrivileges: yes
Root0: C:\Users\Houari\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
Root1: C:\Users\Houari\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
Root2: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Root3: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
UserInstall: C:\Users\Houari\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserConfig: C:\Users\Houari\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserData: C:\Users\Houari\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonInstall: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Invokers:
```

Error message:

> The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance). Generally, this is a temporary state.
>
> More info: https://miktex.org/kb/fix-503
>
> responseCode="503"

PS: I tried to reinstall MIKTeX but the problem not solve.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! There was a bug in the last update, which caused the installations to no more work after update. You'll have to wait the problem is solved.

Comment: Due to the issues discussed in https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/346, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/501786/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/501795/35864 MikTeX has temporarily taken the repositories offline to avoid spreading a problematic update, see https://miktex.org/alert/update-problem-7147. Temporarily you will not be able to update or install new packages. If possible wait until the problem is resolved (the developer is aware of it, so it should be resolved soon). If you need updates *now*, try a local repository:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462203/35864

Comment: Ok thanks, i'll wait until the problem solved!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was due to a temporary shutdown of the MiKTeX repository that is over now.